# Issue in sending email using phpmailer

Tags: php

I am trying to send mail using PHPMailer and my code looks like this.

```
require 'inc/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$email_body = "";
$email_body = $email_body . "Name: " . $name . "<br>";
$email_body = $email_body . "Email: " . $email . "<br>";
$email_body = $email_body . "Message: " . $message;

    $mail->isSendmail(); 
    $mail->setFrom($email, $name);  
    $mail->addAddress('examp@gmail.com', 'example'); 
    $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer sendmail test'; 
    $mail->msgHTML($email_body);  
    //send the message, check for errors
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error is: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "Message sent!";
    }
```

But it is showing error:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\class.phpmailer.php on line 1134

I have downloaded by PHPMailer from https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

Comment: Is local sendmail working?

Comment: either you have a look at the following line why it is taking so long time or increase `max_execution_time` by `ini_set()`

Comment: @violator667  local sendmail is not working.

Comment: @ChimedPalden so how you going to send email? you are trying to use `isSendmail()` and you dont have local sendmail woking

Answer (score 1):

This probably happends because phpmailer is validating the email address...

**Solution 1:** Because you entered the email address **yourself** you could replace the following function in `class.phpmailer.php`:

```
public static function ValidateAddress($address) {
    if ((defined('PCRE_VERSION')) && (version_compare(PCRE_VERSION, '8.0') >= 0)) {
      return preg_match('/^(?!(?>(?1)"?(?>\\\[ -~]|[^"])"?(?1)){255,})(?!(?>(?1)"?(?>\\\[ -~]|[^"])"?(?1)){65,}@)((?>(?>(?>((?>(?>(?>\x0D\x0A)?[     ])+|(?>[    ]*\x0D\x0A)?[   ]+)?)(\((?>(?2)(?>[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\'*-\[\]-\x7F]|\\\[\x00-\x7F]|(?3)))*(?2)\)))+(?2))|(?2))?)([!#-\'*+\/-9=?^-~-]+|"(?>(?2)(?>[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-!#-\[\]-\x7F]|\\\[\x00-\x7F]))*(?2)")(?>(?1)\.(?1)(?4))*(?1)@(?!(?1)[a-z0-9-]{64,})(?1)(?>([a-z0-9](?>[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)(?>(?1)\.(?!(?1)[a-z0-9-]{64,})(?1)(?5)){0,126}|\[(?:(?>IPv6:(?>([a-f0-9]{1,4})(?>:(?6)){7}|(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\]]){7,})((?6)(?>:(?6)){0,5})?::(?7)?))|(?>(?>IPv6:(?>(?6)(?>:(?6)){5}:|(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){5,})(?8)?::(?>((?6)(?>:(?6)){0,3}):)?))?(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])(?>\.(?9)){3}))\])(?1)$/isD', $address);
    } elseif (function_exists('filter_var')) { //Introduced in PHP 5.2
        if(filter_var($address, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === FALSE) {
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
    } else {
         return preg_match('/^(?:[\w\!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`\{\|\}\~]+\.)*[\w\!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`\{\|\}\~]+@(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_](?:[a-zA-Z0-9_\-](?!\.)){0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9_-]?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9_](?:[a-zA-Z0-9_\-](?!$)){0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9_]?)|(?:\[(?:(?:[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\]))$/', $address);
    }
}
```

with:

```
public static function ValidateAddress($address) {
    return true;
}
```

---

**Solution 2:**
This is the easiest way to fix it (probably). Paste the following line at the top of your code.

```
set_time_limit(60); //60 seconds = 1 minute
```

---

**Solution 3:**
Try this: [How to correctly fix phpMailer max execution time error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642491/how-to-correctly-fix-phpmailer-max-execution-time-error)
(Idk if this actually works.)

---

**EDIT:** You also forgot the: `$mail->isHTML(true);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail->isHTML(true); 
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer sendmail test'; 
$mail->Body    = $email_body;
```